# UIPickerView crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uipickerview

I am at loss as far as why there is a corruption in the below code. I pretty much lifted the existing "implementation" from examples. Still, when I try to change the value of my picker controller, code crashes because cloudProviders points to some random memory.
Please advise.

```
//  SettingsViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController
    <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *cloudProviders;

@end

//  SettingsViewController.m

#import "SettingsViewController.h"

@interface SettingsViewController ()

@end

@implementation SettingsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    _cloudProviders = @[@"BOX", @"Yandex", @"Other"];
    NSLog(@"Executing viewDidLoad");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_picker release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PickerView DataSource
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _cloudProviders.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
        titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
        forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _cloudProviders[row];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PickerView Delegate
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSLog(@"Executing didSelectRow");
}

/*
-(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
 */
@end
```

Also, what tools do people use to track down memory leaks and such on iOS? Is there something that could tell me who modified my pointer?

Thank you

Comment: just make sure you only connected 1 IB to one object, check your interface builder

Comment: What is crash message?

Comment: It looks like you're using manual memory management (since you're calling `release` in `dealloc`).  In that case, you should probably do `self.cloudProviders = @[...];` in `viewDidLoad`.  If you switch to using ARC, some of these issues are handled for you.

Comment: I still do not understand why the two are not equivalent - that my property would be generated as _cloudProviers, but you are correct. self.cloudProviders survives.
Thank you

Comment: Anna,
I am sorry again. How do I mark your answer as correct on stackoverflow? I do not see an option to do that.
Must be a bad day. I apologize and thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Anna is correct.
Setting the property as self.cloudProviders solves the problem.